# Проблема с массивом java

Tags: java, android, массивы

Есть активити `Test`.

После объявления имени класса я создаю массив `String[] array;`. Потом где то в глубине кода я инициализирую массив `array = new String [] {urlString};`.

Но почему то он перезаписывается, т.е. индекс постоянно нулевой. А нужно на оборот, добавлять постоянно строку в массив. Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Массив статичен, в него нельзя динамически добавлять элементы.
Используйте `ArrayList<String>`

в одном месте делаете `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

и дальше уже `list.add("my new string");`
и она будет добавляться в конец

Answer (score 5):

Это происходит, потому, что когда вы вызываете `new String[]` объект переинициализируется. Попробуйте использовать `Коллекции`

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array.add("строка"); // Для добавления используйте метод add()
array.get(0); // для доступа к строке по индексу используйте метод get()
```